# How to remove brackets and commas from tuple

Tags: python

I'm trying to get the top 5 characters of a string printed.
For example, if I typed "aaaabbbbcccddfg"

Is there anyway I can change the output so it becomes a:4,b:4,c:3,d:2,f:1 ?

Codes are:

```
import sys
from collections import Counter

try:
    string = sys.argv[1]

    counts=Counter(string.lower()) # Counter({'l': 2, 'H': 1, 'e': 1, 'o': 1})
    lista = counts.most_common(5)

    print lista

except ValueError:
    print "Error"
```

The current result is: [("a", 4),("b", 4), ("c", 3), ("d", 2), ("f", 1)]

Comment: so essentially, a dictionary?

Comment: You want to print how you would in a dictionary? Could you pls include the output of `lista` there

Comment: yes but if i'm not wrong, dictionary still has the ' ', is there anyway to remove that from the dictionary? Sorry, pretty new to python

Comment: What is the point of removing the ' '? Your values are obviously strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works for python 2.7:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import sys
from collections import Counter

try:
    string = sys.argv[1]
    counts=Counter(string.lower()) # Counter({'l': 2, 'H': 1, 'e': 1, 'o': 1})
    lista = counts.most_common(5)
    print (lista)
    for l in lista:
        print(':'.join(str(e) for e in l), end=",")

except ValueError:
    print ("Error")
```

Comment: I'm actually using python 2.7. Is there something similar to the end="," in 2.7?

Comment: Add "from __future__ import print_function" in your code.

Answer (score 0):

This works for Python 2.7

```
import sys
from collections import Counter

try:
    string = sys.argv[1]
    counts=Counter(string.lower())
    lista = counts.most_common(5)
    dict_lista = dict((x, y) for x, y in lista)
    print lista
    for key,item in dict_lista.items():
        print key + ":" + str(item)

except ValueError:
    print "Error"
```

It first forms a dictionary then prints it's keys and items without the `" "`s - I left the original tuples just for comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Just do the following :

```
for key,val in dict(lista).items(): 
       print( str(key) + ':' + str(val), end=', ')
```

This will print `a:4, b:4, c:3, d:2, f:1`

Answer (score 0):

One line solution using list comprehension:

```
listb = ",".join([str(a) + ":" + str(b) for a, b in lista])
print listb # output => a:4,b:4,c:3,d:2,g:1
```

Answer (score 0):

Yup.

```
print ','.join(map(lambda (c,n): "{letter}:{count}".format(letter=c,count=n), lista))
```

There's a lot going on there, so let's break it down.
`"{letter}:{count}"` is a [format string](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) and this is how you should create strings from data.  Starting in Python 3.6 this gets a bit easier.  Once you're used to formatting strings like this you will be so happy.

`lambda (c,n): ...`  This is a lambda function.  In other words it is a function definition that can be repetedly applied to the array `lista` without having to be defined above in your code.  The (c,n) is doing something here called "Unpacking" where the elements in `lista` are pairs, so this splits the first element into it's two parts and stores them in `c` and `n` respectively.
Lambda functions play really well with `map` which takes a function as an argument and a collection, then applies that argument to that collection and returns a list of the results.

The last thing is `str.join()`.  This is an efficient way to put strings together.  It is a method of strings, that takes as an argument a list of strings, and returns a new string that is delimited by the original string.  For example `','.join(['a','b','c'])` would result in `'a,b,c'`

EDIT:
bug fix and One-liner:

```
print ','.join(map(lambda (c,n): "{letter}:{count}".format(letter=c,count=n), Counter(sys.argv[1].lower()).most_common(5))) if len(sys.argv) > 1 else "Error"
```